# How to include nested and sibling associations in active record to_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have a Course model with 2 associations to another model, Tree:

```
belongs_to  :interaction_outline, :class_name => "Tree", 
                                  :foreign_key => "interaction_outline_id"
belongs_to  :token_outline, :class_name => "Tree", 
                                  :foreign_key => "token_outline_id"
```

I read [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) and was able to include sibling associations in my controller.

```
@course.to_json(:include=> [:interaction_outline, :token_outline]
```

I was also able to get multiply nested associations:

```
@course.to_json(:include=>{:interaction_outline=> 
                              {:include=> {:tree_node=> 
                                     {:include=> :definition}}}} )
```

BUT I cannot get both sibling AND multiply nested includes:

```
@course.to_json (:include=> [{:interaction_outline=> 
                               {:include=> {:tree_node=> 
                                    {:include=> :definition}}}}, 
                            {:token_outline=> 
                               {:include=> {:tree_node=> 
                                   {:include=> :definition}}}} ] ) 
#NoMethodError (undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass)
#the error you get when the syntax or the association is wrong
```

I tried this, too:

```
@course.to_json (:include=> [:interaction_outline=> 
                               {:include=> {:tree_node=> 
                                   {:include=> :definition}}}, 
                          :token_outline=> 
                             {:include=> {:tree_node=> 
                                    {:include=> :definition}}} ] ) 
#same error
```

What is the right syntax here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're really close.  Just use hash notation instead of array.

```
@course.to_json (:include=> {:interaction_outline=> 
                               {:include=> {:tree_node=> 
                                    {:include=> :definition}}}, 
                             :token_outline=> 
                               {:include=> {:tree_node=> 
                                   {:include=> :definition}}}} )
```

Comment: Postscript: generally it seems a bad idea to mix array and hash notation. If you convert to all hash, however, there is a catch, if one sibling association has an include and one does not, the one that does not needs to become a prop for an empty hash, like this:   {:include=> {:tree_node=> {}, :definitions=> {}, :edit_lists=> {:include=> :edits}}}.

Comment: thank you!!! quite ugly but it works, have you found any gem that would made that prettier?

Comment: What if the recursion is endless?  Is there a way to traverse it to the last leaf without explicitly specifying n nested hashes?  PS: Hi Ogz.

Comment: @Midwire Hey! I don't think it's possible to do what you want with Rails' baked in JSON support.  Take a look around to see, and let me know if I'm wrong about that.  The first thing that comes to mind is to create a custom to_json method on each model that you want to be included.

Comment: Here's a simple example of what I mean: https://gist.github.com/1499154.  It seems like there should already be something out there that does this for you.